# Network requests are not always happening after click() command in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to automation testing. I'm training to automate with cypress and I faced the problem that network requests (GET-XHR requests in particular) are not always being triggered after click() command in cypress.

I have a custom command in my `/support/commands.js`, which is supposed to click 'Add to comparison' link and return the title of the item added to comparison:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("addToComparison", function (index) {
  cy.get(".vit-item").eq(index).find(".tovar-compare").click();
  return cy
    .get(".vit-item")
    .eq(index)
    .find(".vit-name")
    .invoke("text")
    .then((title) => {
      return title;
    });
});
```

Then I call this command in my `/integration/smoke.spec.js:`

```
describe("Add 2 items to comparison", () => {
  it("Add 2 items to comparison", () => {
    cy.visit("https://elmir.ua/cell_phones/");
    cy.addToComparison(0);
    cy.addToComparison(1);
    cy.get("#top-paging .compare-link").click();
  });
});
```

When users do the same actions manually on the site, after clicking 'Add to comparison' link (`cy.get(".vit-item").eq(index).find(".tovar-compare").click()` in the `addToComparison` function), GET-request to  URL `https://elmir.ua/response/compare.php` is triggered, but when I run my test, the GET-request is being triggered from time to time, but almost never for both items in the test.
[Screenshot of Cypress test Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vb3W.png)

I've tried chaining calls of `addToComparison()` with `then()` like this, but it did not make any difference:

```
describe("Add 2 items to comparison", () => {
  it("Add 2 items to comparison", () => {
    cy.visit("https://elmir.ua/cell_phones/");
    cy.addToComparison(0).then((item1) => {
      cy.addToComparison(1).then((item2) => {
        cy.get("#top-paging .compare-link").click();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Also, I've tried to avoid creating a custom function and just call `get()` method directly in the test, but it didn't make difference either:

```
describe("Add 2 items to comparison", () => {
  it("Add 2 items to comparison", () => {
    cy.visit("https://elmir.ua/cell_phones/");
    cy.get(".vit-item").eq(0).find(".tovar-compare").click();
    cy.get(".vit-item").eq(1).find(".tovar-compare").click();
    cy.get("#top-paging .compare-link").click();
  });
});
```

The html snippet

```
<li class="vit-item">
  <section class="vit-info">
    <a
      href="/cell_phones/mobile_phone_samsung_a207f_galaxy_a20s_32_duos_red_sm-a207fzrdsek.html"
      class="vit-name"
      >Мобильный телефон Samsung A207F Galaxy A20s/32 Duos Red
      (SM-A207FZRDSEK)</a
    >
    <p class="vit-desc">
      6,5" / 720х1560 / IPS / ОЗУ - 3 ГБ / 32 ГБ встроенной памяти / Сканер
      отпечатка пальца / 4G / 2 SIM / 4000 мАч
    </p>
    <div class="vit-buy">
      <div class="btn-buy ready-1 status-1 buy-1000663 no-print">
        <div class="no-print ready btn" onclick="btn_buy(1000663);">
          <svg><use xlink:href="#v-basket"></use></svg>В корзину
        </div>
        <span class="status stat-1">есть в наличии</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="price vit-cost"
      ><zl>7</zl><zj>0</zj><zf>9</zf><zy>4</zy><zf>5</zf><zr>0</zr><zb>8</zb
      ><zu>3</zu><zx>9</zx><zv>6</zv><ze>1</ze><zz>9</zz><ze>9</ze><zo>6</zo
      ><zu>9</zu>&nbsp;грн</span
    ><br /><span class="warr"
      ><a target="_blank" href="/faq.html#q17">Гарантия:</a>&nbsp;12 мес.</span
    ><br /><span
      product="1000663"
      class="icon-eye view-rest internal-link link no-print"
      ><svg><use xlink:href="#v-avail"></use></svg>Посмотреть наличие</span
    ><br /><a
      class="icon-mail notify no-print"
      href="/?module=profile&amp;tab=subscribe&amp;add=1000663"
      ><svg><use xlink:href="#v-notify"></use></svg>Уведомить</a
    ><br /><a
      class="icon-reviews no-print"
      href="/cell_phones/mobile_phone_samsung_a207f_galaxy_a20s_32_duos_red_sm-a207fzrdsek.html#reviews"
      ><svg><use xlink:href="#v-reviews"></use></svg>Отзывы (0)</a
    ><br /><span product="1000663" class="tovar-wishlist no-print"
      ><svg><use xlink:href="#v-wish"></use></svg></span
    ><br /><span class="catalog-tovar-id">Код товара: 1000663</span><br /><span
      compare_id="lg47"
      parent_id="97516"
      class="no-print tovar-compare add-link"
      >Добавить к сравнению</span
    >
  </section>
</li>
```

Usually only the first run of the test passes, but after I re-run the test the issue appears (but I'm not sure about that).

I suppose I'm doing something terribly wrong, because this is not the only site where clicking the element does not trigger the GET XHR-request (well, I triggers, but only some of them). I tried another site with very similar logic and there was the same issue.

Please help.

Comment: Can you also include the pertinent html surrounding the test in question, please?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question. Edited the question with the html-snippet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8224
Cypress finds the element `cy.get(".vit-item").eq(index).find(".tovar-compare")` when it is visible and clickable, but not all the EventListeners are already attached to the element. You can workaround this situation with the help of `cypress-pipe` plugin